# I am so sure that I have already put all data and model, but I still Get this error

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

this is the error stack.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_train.py", line 55, in <module>
    test()
  File "my_train.py", line 51, in test
    train.train()
  File "my_train.py", line 37, in train
    outputs = self.model(inputs)
  File "/home/rs/andy/python-venv/torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rs/andy/andy/MyFCN/model/FCN/FCN32.py", line 12, in forward
    y = self.up_sampling(feature, None, 512)
  File "/home/rs/andy/andy/MyFCN/model/FCN/FCN.py", line 47, in up_sampling
    y = self.bn(batch_norm)(y)
  File "/home/rs/andy/python-venv/torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rs/andy/python-venv/torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py", line 168, in forward
    return F.batch_norm(
  File "/home/rs/andy/python-venv/torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2421, in batch_norm
    return torch.batch_norm(
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper__cudnn_batch_norm)
```

This is all my code:
I think the error line will happen in this file as I put data to GPU in this section.
train:

```py
import torch.cuda
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import dataset
from model.FCN import FCN32


class Train:
    def __init__(self, dataset_path, model, batch_size, shuffle):
        self.dataset = dataset.ObtTrainDataset(dataset_path)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
        print(f"using {self.device}")
        self.model = model

    def train(self):
        self.model = self.model.to(self.device)
        epoch = 10
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(self.device)
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
        dl = DataLoader(dataset=self.dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=False)
        for i in range(epoch):
            print("------------{} begin--------------".format(i))
            self.model.train()
            running_loss = 0.0
            j = 0
            for data in dl:
                j += 1
                inputs, target = data
                inputs = inputs.to(self.device)
                target = target.to(self.device)
                target = torch.squeeze(target, 1).long().to(self.device)

                optimizer.zero_grad()

                outputs = self.model(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, target)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                running_loss += loss.cpu().item()
            print(running_loss)
            torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), f"models/obt_10_{i}.pth")



def test():
    dataset = "data/obt/image"
    model = FCN32(256, 5)
    train = Train(dataset, model, 8, True)
    train.train()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

model code:
This is the implementation of FCN32s, I think there is nothing that goes run. But the error stack indicts that the `FCN.py` file line 47 wrong.
FCN:

```py
from torch import nn

from model.FCN.vgg import VGG16


class FCN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes, backbone="vgg16"):
        super().__init__()
        all_backones = ["vgg16"]
        if backbone not in all_backones:
            raise ValueError(f"backbone must be ont of the item in {all_backones}")

        if backbone == "vgg16":
            self.features = VGG16(input_size)
            self.num_classes = num_classes

            self.deconv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 512, 3, 2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
            self.deconv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 3, 2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
            self.deconv3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 3, 2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
            self.deconv4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 3, 2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
            self.deconv5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 3, 2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
            self.classifier = nn.Conv2d(32, num_classes, kernel_size=1, padding="same")
            self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d
            self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError("please implement it")

    def up_sampling(self, x1, x2=None, batch_norm=None):
        deconv = None
        assert batch_norm is not None
        if batch_norm == 512:
            deconv = self.deconv1
        elif batch_norm == 256:
            deconv = self.deconv2
        elif batch_norm == 128:
            deconv = self.deconv3
        elif batch_norm == 64:
            deconv = self.deconv4
        elif batch_norm == 32:
            deconv = self.deconv5
        y = deconv(x1)
        y = self.relu(y)
        if x2 is None:
            y = self.bn(batch_norm)(y)
        else:
            y = self.bn(batch_norm)(y + x2)
        return y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

FCN32s

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

from model.FCN import FCN


class FCN32(FCN):
    def forward(self, x):
        feature = self.features(x)["pool32"]
        y = self.up_sampling(feature, None, 512)
        y = self.up_sampling(y, None, 256)
        y = self.up_sampling(y, None, 128)
        y = self.up_sampling(y, None, 64)
        y = self.up_sampling(y, None, 32)
        y = self.classifier(y)
        return y
```

dataset:

```py
import os
from glob import glob

import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms as T


class ObtTrainDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_path=r"data/obt/image", mode="train"):
        assert mode in ("train", "val", "test")
        self.image_path = image_path
        self.image_list = glob(os.path.join(self.image_path, "*.npy"))
        self.mode = mode

        if mode in ("train", "val"):
            self.mask_path = self.image_path

        self.transform_x = T.Compose(
            [T.ToTensor(), T.Resize((256, 256))])
        self.transform_mask = T.Compose([T.ToTensor(), T.Resize((256, 256))])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self.mode in ("train", "val"):
            image_name = os.path.basename(self.image_list[index])

            X = np.load(os.path.join(self.image_path, image_name))

            masks = np.load(os.path.join(self.image_path + "Masks", image_name))

            X = X / 1.0
            masks = masks / 1.0
            X = self.transform_x(X)
            masks = self.transform_mask(masks)
            X = X.type(torch.FloatTensor)
            masks = masks.type(torch.FloatTensor)

            return X, masks

        else:
            X = Image.open(self.image_list[index])
            X = self.transform_x(X)
            path = self.image_list[index]
            return X, path

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_list)
```

**I have already debuged it for 3 hours** help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your use of [`BatchNorm2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html?highlight=batchnorm2d#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d) is very odd. In your base class, `FCN`, you do not define a batch norm layer, but rather only a "place holder": `self.bn` is *not* a layer, but rather a function that returns a layer, given the parameter `num_features`. Then, at each forward pass, you create, *from scratch* a new `BatchNorm2d` layer, and forward your features through this layer.
Needless to say, that the new layer that is created during the forward pass is not moved to the GPU: the `.to(self.device)` is called *before* the forward pass and *before* the batch norm layer was created.

But this is not the worst thing here: the fact that you create a new batch norm layer for each forward pass means that the layer cannot learn the statistics of your data and thus is unable to function properly.